# Write file permission and terminal command parameter invoke on mac (firemonkey delphi)

Tags: macos, delphi, terminal, command, firemonkey

i wrote simple apps to edit hosts file... but it requires elevation which i do not know how to implement elevation in mac whenever user click the button

> `procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject); 
>       var MyFile : TextFile;
>       FileD : TStringList;
>       FileL : string;
>        begin
>         if not memo1.Text.IsEmpty then
>           begin
>             FileL := '/etc/hosts';
>             FileD := Tstringlist.create();
>             FileD.Text := memo1.Text;
>             Filed.SaveToFile(FileL); // Required elevation
>             Filed.Free;
>           end;`

i want to interact with mac shell within my firemonkey apps..
in example

> `sudo mv /users/name/documents/temphosts /etc/hosts`

so i could overwrite the hosts file after asking user permission.

Comment: It may help to provide an example of what you're trying to do in Windows -- I think it is still unclear.

Comment: What on Earth has this got to do with Delphi or Firemonkey? What is a stringlist.savetofile? What do you really want to do?

Comment: im sorry, i edited the whole question

Comment: `Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile()` turns your function into a one-liner. I think the user should not find it too hard to edit their hosts file with a text editor. I also encourage you to give controls and variables meaningful names. Spend more time thinking about naming. Otherwise your code will be write-only.